# Keeping reference to DB and collection MongoDB python

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I wonder is it fine if I keep a reference to a db and a collection as class members ?

Like that

```
from pymongo import MongoClient


class ClientDataStore(object):
    BASE_MONGO_CONNECTION_URL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/'
    MAIN_DB_NAME = "bank"
    CLIENT_COLLECTION_NAME = "client"

    def __init__(self):
        self.mongo = MongoClient(ClientDataStore.BASE_MONGO_CONNECTION_URL)
        self.db = self.mongo[ClientDataStore.MAIN_DB_NAME]
        self.client_collection = self.db[ClientDataStore.CLIENT_COLLECTION_NAME]

    def get_client_info(self, id):
        client = self.client_collection.find_one({"_id": id})
        return client
```

Will it keep the opened connection or it will open it as necessary ?

Or I should open the db and get the collection all only when I need this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a good idea. MongoClient has a connection pool that keeps open connections indefinitely. Keeping an open connection will reduce latency and increase throughput in your application. See the [Connection Pool FAQ for PyMongo](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/faq.html#how-does-connection-pooling-work-in-pymongo).